# Bundle Identifer & all Certificates exist in Xcode, in Developer Account the Bundle Identifer is missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bundle-identifier

i just created a new app. In Xcode everything like Team, Provisioning Profile and Signing Certificate is registered and i can build my app successfully. I enabled the automatically signing so Xcode should register  the bundle identifier in my developer account. But this isn't happen. In my developer account i see all my other bundle identifiers, where i used the same Signing Certificate. Now im confused, cause normally Xcode should register the bundle identifier in my developer account right? I don't want to create the bundle identifier in my developer account manually, cause i enabled that Xcode should do it.

So maybe you have some tips for me how to handle the problem.

Comment: I have tried to register my bundle identifier manually but i get the error message 'An App ID with Identifier is not available. Please enter a different string.'. So it looks like the identifier exist somewhere but in the member center i don't see it in the app ID category. Someone any idea what i can do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just changed my app-id and now everything is working. Don't know what the problem was.